# Why is only one media query not working?

Tags: html, css

I have some media queries but I was asked to do one for larger screens. 
I modified this media query:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 900px){
.right div{
    padding-left: 3rem;       
}

.right div:nth-child(1){
    padding-right: 3rem;
}

.right div:nth-child(1), .right div:nth-child(2){
    padding-top: 3rem;
}

.right div:last-child{
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
}
}
```

But then I added the new media query and modified the smaller query adding a max-width and the new media query is not loading (the one with min-width: 1600px):

```
 @media only screen and (min-width: 900px)  and (max-width: 1599px){
   /*code*/
}

@media only screen and(min-width: 1600px){
.right div:nth-child(4){
    padding-right: 6rem;
}

.right div{
    padding-left: 3rem;

}

.right div:nth-child(1){
    padding-right: 3rem;
}

.right div:nth-child(1), .right div:nth-child(2){
    padding-top: 3rem;
}

.right div:last-child{
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
}
}
```

This is how I had all my media queries before:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {    
      /*some code*/      
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 899px) {   
     /*some code*/
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 900px){
    /* some code */
}
```

Comment: Which part doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry, will edit, but it's the querie with (min-width: 1600px)

Comment: If the min-width 1600px isn't loading then you should start looking for missing semi colons in the previous query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a petty mistake. You have no space between your `and` and `(min...)`

Change:

```
@media only screen and(min-width: 1600px){
```

to :

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1600px){
```

Advice: Use [CSS validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input) to catch these kinds of mistakes.